# Strange behaviour from setInterval vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having some strange behaviours with the `setInternal` in my vue.js component. Below is the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
  {{ hours }} : {{ minutes }} : {{ seconds }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {
  Vue,
  Component,
  Prop,
} from 'vue-property-decorator';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component
export default class Countdown extends Vue {
  @Prop() private end!: Date;

  @Prop({ default: 1000 })
  interval!: number;

  private remaining!: number;

  get hours() {
    debugger;
    return Math.floor(this.remaining / 3600);
  }

  get minutes() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-operators
    return Math.floor(this.remaining % 3600 / 60);
  }

  get seconds() {
    return Math.floor(this.remaining % 3600 % 60);
  }

  created() {
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
    const self = this;
    return setInterval(() => {
      self.remaining = (moment(self.end).toDate().getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / self.interval;
    }, self.interval);
  }
}
</script>
```

Firstly, I thought using an arrow function i.e `=> { }` would allow me to use `this.end` or `this.remaining` but this isn't the case as I have to use `const self = this;` in order for it work work.

In addition, the computed properties `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` aren't being updated. I've put a breakpoint on each of these and none of them get touched as the DOM always displays `NaN NaN NaN`

Does anyone understand what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, the problem is private  remaining: number  is undefined, set it an initial value, example private  remaining: number = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using [Definite Assignment Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions), and you don't get any error, this.remaining is undefined, and you get NaN, at some point you need to assign it some value:

directly:

```
private  remaining: number = this.calculate();

calculate() {
   return (moment(this.end)
            .toDate()
            .getTime() -
             new Date().getTime()) /
             this.interval;
  }

refresh() {
   setInterval(() => this.remaining = this.calculate(), this.interval);
}
```

For some reason assign the first value directly inside setInterval not update the value. Will be interesting to kwon why :(.